# JTextPane .getText() not preserving whitespace for HTML?

Tags: java, html, swing, whitespace, jtextpane

If I have an editable JTextPane with content type set to text/html I don't see whitespace preserved. I.E.: if I run the following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
public class HtmlPasteTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextPane PANE;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HtmlPasteTest();
    }
    public HtmlPasteTest() {        
        HTMLEditorKit KIT = new HTMLEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument DOC = (HTMLDocument)(KIT.createDefaultDocument());
        PANE = new JTextPane();
        PANE.setContentType("text/html");
        PANE.setEditorKit(KIT);
        PANE.setDocument(DOC);
        JButton dump = new JButton("DUMP");
        dump.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(dump, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(PANE, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(PANE.getText());     
    }
}
```

... then type "a     b" & click the DUMP button I'd expect to see something like the following:

```
      a &nbsp; &nbsp; b
```

... however instead I see the following:

```
      a     b
```

... am I missing some sort of setting here ?

Comment: Why do you expect a space to be converted to a non-breakable space? After all, `U+0020` and `U+00A0` are entirely different characters.

Comment: Good point - had not thought of it that way. However I cannot enter a &nbsp; via the keyboard, so the end result is that concurrent whitespace entered by a user *cannot* be retrieved.

Comment: ... and I cannot assume concurrent whitespace from the document was entered by the client, as they can paste in HTML from other pages, and in a lot of cases whitespace here is for HTML source readability ...

Comment: Maybe you are asking the wrong question? To me it looks like Swing shouldn’t render adjacent white-space as multiple spaces (outside of a `white-space: pre` context) in the first place. But to my experience it doesn’t help thinking about what Swing does right or wrong, Swing programming is work-around programming… So probably the best thing to do is to program your own action inserting either non-breakable spaces or `<pre>` parts into the document and bind it to the space key.

Comment: *Swing programming is work-around programming* - indeed :-)

Comment: what I'm going to do is add a DocumentListener & try to figure out the right thing on a case-by-case basis. Ah well.

Comment: @DaveCarpeneto, No, don't use a DocumentListener. I just provided two better choices.

Comment: What is in the HTML which would suggest that white space is important?  White space would normally be ignored/gotten rid of unless it is enclosed in in a `pre` tag or similar.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : I'm trying to allow users to enter text the way they would in a word processor, so spacing as entered by the user should be preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I cannot enter a `&nbsp;` via the keyboard

You have a couple of different options to translate the "space" when it is entered:

1. You can us a `DocumentFilter` to filter the characters as they are entered into the Document. . Whenever you enter a "Space" you simply insert `&nbsp;` into the Document. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information and examples.
2. You can use `KeyBindings` to create a custom Action to insert the `&nbsp;` when the Space key is used. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information. You should extend `TextAction` to implement the `Action`.

Comment: DocumentFilter really is the best option here. Thanks so much for suggesting.